# Extend Contact Form with Autoresponse

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I'm using the following contact form on my site:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["email"]<>'') {
        $ToEmail = 'info@mysite.com';
        $EmailSubject = 'Message from Website';
        $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
        $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
        $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br /><br />";
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br /><br />";
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Birthday: ".$_POST["birthday"]."<br /><br /><br />";
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message:<br /><br />".nl2br($_POST["comments"])."";
        mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Fehler!");
?>
```

How can I extend it to send an email to the person who submitted the entry with a custom text? Something like "Thank you for your message. We will come back to you within the next 48 hours."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add them in a CC header?

```
$mailheader .= "CC: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain it correctly. I want the sender to receive a custom message via email. Something like "Thank you for your message. We will come back to you within the next 48 hours."

Comment: In that case I would just use the same sort of message structure you have, and send a separate second message to their address instead of your own with a different subject and body.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to put it together, but I don't receive the email when sending a test email. This is the code I tried:

http://pastebin.com/AjtKiFYV

Comment: You are missing the closing '}' from your if statement at the top.

Comment: Ok, but if it is not in your example, and the missing code makes it not parse, it becomes difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You may use multiple email address in the following line:

```
$ToEmail = 'info@mysite.com, another_email@email.com';
```

this `$ToEmail` accept multiple. Hope it will work also.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain it correctly. I want the sender to receive a custom message via email. Something like "Thank you for your message. We will come back to you within the next 48 hours."